# Remove the first word in a string when this word equals to "the"

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string "the city of Seattle" or "the city of New York". I hope to remove the word "the" and convert it to "city of Seattle". If the string is "a city of Seattle", it should keep the same.

I tried to use python regex to solve the problem, but it failed. I believe my regex is incorrect.

```
s = "the city of seattle"
s = s.replace(/^the /, '');
print s

s1 = "a city of seattle"
s1 = s1.replace(/^the /, '');
print s1
```

The expected result is: "city of seattle" and "a city of seattle", but I got the syntax error.

Comment: Python doesn't have regex literals. Please read about [the `re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re). (Also, in the future, please include exact error messages instead of just "syntax error". The one you got probably includes helpful information. See [ask].)

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python regex tutorial", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: You can also approach this using the `startswith` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python (assuming you're coming from JavaScript), *regular expression literals* are simply strings (enclosed within quotes, not `/.../`), and replacing a regex requires the `re` module (specifically the `re.sub` function):

```
import re

s = "the city of seattle"
s = re.sub('^the ', '', s)
print s

s1 = "a city of seattle"
s1 = re.sub('^the ', '', s1)
print s1
```

Output:

```
city of seattle
a city of seattle
```

Comment: thanks, it should be " '^the ' " rather than " /^the / "

Answer (score 0):

A method that doesn't require `re`:

```py
s = "the city of seattle"

word = "the"
if s.startswith(word):
    s = s[len(word):].lstrip()

print(s)
# "city of seattle"
```